# Showing Details with Drupal Views 3

Tags: views

I have a table structure for fee details as

```
fid     
name    
description
currency
fee     
instalments
created
```

This fee schedule has N no of instalments and storing in a cross ref table as

```
iid
fid
instalment_no
amount
payable_by
```

This fee schedule has associated students and are storing in a cross ref table as

```
fid
uid
```

I need to show the details of a fee schedule to end user with all installments and students. Is this possible to get this fee detail page using views 3.

Please help me to write the SQL to fetch fee details with students and fee instalments.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

One of my friend suggested me to create three displays in views each showing result from each table i.e. first display to show the fee details, second fee instalments and third to show the fee students. Then in page display all three views by using the functions views_get_view. Thanks Inian :)

While doing the way Inian suggested, I found attachment as a display type and that solved my problem and I don't have to write any custom code now.

Umar

Comment: @refineo I don't have much reputation points to reply my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my friend suggested me to create three displays in views each showing result from each table i.e. first display to show the fee details, second fee instalments and third to show the fee students. Then in page display all three views by using the functions views_get_view. Thanks Inian :)

While doing the way Inian suggested, I found attachment as a display type and that solved my problem and I don't have to write any custom code now.